# Firebase signInWithEmaiLlink - can the link be made available on UI instead of email

Tags: firebase, authentication

I have a requirement where I want to enable signin from UI page. Requirement goes like this

a. Show a textbox where user can enter his email Id
b. Once he enters the email id and clicks submit, he gets the URL link to signin in the response.
c. User can now click on the link to login to the firebase app.

I understand that the link to signin is sent in email only but is there a way to fetch it on the UI.

Regards
Raghav

Comment: Don't use the hammer to scoop ice cream. Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but you shouldn't. The purpose of email linking is to verify that a valid email is submitted and verified, which as far as I understand from your question, you kind of want to ommit.

In [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth) is shown the normal flow and almost at the bottom it says that a [Firebase Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) is created to complete the flow, so you should be able to catch that link if you need to.

Comment: Thanks but i am not seeing a way to catch the link . - other than from Firebase console - which means that i have to manually copy the link value.

Answer (score 1):

You'll use sendSignInLinkToEmail to tell Firebase to generate the dynamic link and send it to your users email. sendSignInLinkToEmail requires two things, the email and an actionCodeSettings object which includes a redirect url.

You'll need to handle the signin and confirm logic at that redirect URL. The [official example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/email-link.html) shows you how to grab your current URL (the redirect URL) and, using isSignInWithEmailLink, conditionally start the signin process.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use the REST API
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest

Or the admin SDK
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#generatesigninwithemaillink